# How do I define _POSIX_VERSION in my configure command?

Tags: linux, gcc, posix

I have the following error trying to configure cdo with magics:

```
configure: It seems your system does not define _POSIX_VERSION to a value
```

greater-or-equal 200112. This is typically the case when the
compiler is instructed to make ISO C features available only,
e.g. when using gcc -std=c99

```
configure: error: in `/home/zmumba/grads/supplibs/src/cdo-1.9.9/libcdi':
configure: error: POSIX.1-2001 profile required
```

After spending two weeks compiling prerequisite libraries, I ecounter this. The configure command was:

```
./configure --prefix=$SUPPLIBS/cdo  --with-szlib=$SUPPLIBS --with-netcdf=$SUPPLIBS --with-jasper=$SUPPLIBS --with-hdf5=$SUPPLIBS --with-eccodes=$SUPPLIBS/eccodes --with-magics=$SUPPLIBS/magics --with-proj=$SUPPLIBS
```

I need a quick fix, if someone can guide me where I can define the POSIX.1-2001 required. ./configure --help does not help and am not able to get this from SO posts.

Help will be appreciated.
Zilore Mumba

Comment: You could `#include <features.h>`

Comment: Do I put this in the configure script?

Comment: You might be interested by [GNU autoconf](https://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf/), but you can assume that most recent Linux distributions are more or less half POSIX compliant

Comment: Thank you very much @Basile Starynkevitch for your time and effort. The error went away after I added the following at the end of the configure command. "CC=gcc CFLAGS='-DSSIZE_MAX=INT_MAX'"